# Deleting the last 2 lines of the buffer in vi

Tags: regex, unix, vi

I am currently using vi on a file called Nick. I want to delete the last 2 lines in the buffer. How would I do this? I tried using y and /d however I am not sure of the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing this interactively:

1. :$-1  (to go to the second to last line)
2. dG (to delete everything from where the cursor is now)

Comment: I am trying to do this using regex and ex commands exclusively. I tried the command :$-1d but only deletes 1 line.

Answer (score 2):

`Gdk` will do it, followed by `Ctrl-O` if you want to return to where you were before you did it.

(That's `G` to move to the end of the document, `dk` to delete the lines between the current location and the result of the motion `k` i.e. up one line, and `Ctrl-O` just returns you to your previous location.)

If I was actually doing this and didn't have time to think about it, I'd probably use `G` to go to the end of the file, `Shift-V` to enter Visual Line mode, `k` to select the previous line in addition to the current one, then `d` to delete them both.

Comment: This does what I need it to, however I am trying to do it with only ex commands, as I am trying to get used to using them and Regex.

Comment: You should mention that in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Shortest way I know of is

```
:$;-d
```

which says 'delete lines in the range `$;-`'. The range is given in reverse, from the last line `$` to one before the last line `-` (same as `-1`).